# Dygraphs not rendering after Rails 4 upgrade

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jscript, dygraphs

Recently upgraded an old Rails 3 app to the last version of Rails 4. No changes made on dygraphs gem config, nor files, etc. But graphs are not displaying.

Graph div is generated as normal, but the graph is not rendered.

Inspecting elements, I find two errors on js console:

**First Error**

> SyntaxError: missing binding name

found in the first line of compiled file assets/dygraphs/index.self-1de[...].js?body=1. This line:

```
export { default } from './src/dygraph';
```

**Second error**

> ReferenceError: Dygraph is not defined

found in document application.js, on line "new Dygraph" in this function:

```
$(function(){
  $('[data-curve-path]').each(function(){
    var path = $(this).data('curve-path');
    var precision = $(this).data('precision') || 3;
    new Dygraph(this, URLWithRandomString(path), {digitsAfterDecimal: precision, labelsKMB: true});
  });
});
```

Help needed to fix these errors, which I suppose are preventing the graph rendering.